# Add Values of column from 2 different sheets into one sheet with corresponding date

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I trade on 2 accounts and make 2 different sheet for both with Date and Profit/Loss ( attached)

I don't trade on both account daily. i want to make a third sheet which can add the P/L of both sheet according to **date**.
Ex. you can see below , there are no entries for 8th and 13th sept on sheet2 , while sheet1 has.
I want sheet3 to show (2045+0) for 13th sept as per date.

[image]
[image]

Comment: In your current formula use `IFERROR(your formula,0)`. Means when formula will not find any entry with specified date then it will produce error and `IFERROR()` will convert that error to 0 value.

Comment: sorry, can you also tell what formula to use. I am not able to do it !

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A2:B; Sheet2:A2:B}; 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''"; 0)
```